# Flex textflow Paragraphe

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flex4

I have a problem with RichText element and (auto)-indents in paragraphs. (see image)

[image: TextFlow example]

My code:

```
<s:RichText id="richTxt" paddingLeft="60" paddingTop="10"
    width="300">
    <s:content >
    <s:p  >
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Nam eu nulla. nc dapibus, nisi et iaculis feugiat, leo ipsum venenatis enim, a nonummy magna ante vitae diam. <s:br />
                Morbi volutpat leo in ligula. Integer vel magna. Quisque ut magna   nc dapibus, nisi et iaculis feugiat, leo ipsum venenatis enim, a nonummy magna ante vitae diam. <s:br />
                Morbi volutpat leo in ligula. Integer vel magna. Quisque ut magna   nc dapibus, nisi et iaculis feugiat, leo ipsum venenatis enim, a nonummy magna ante vitae d
            </s:p>  
    </s:content>                
</s:RichText>
```

I have tried:

- textAlign
- paragraphStartIndent
- paragraphEndIndent

But either it influence only the first line of the paragraph or nothing happends

**Edit**

The question is: Is it possible to align the text in the paragraph without the indent of the first line?

Thanks for your help

Comment: And your question would be... ?

Comment: Your question seems not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whitespace you see rendered is not an indentation of any kind. It is simply, well, whitespace.

If you would display hidden characters in your code you'd see `<s:p>[return][tab][tab][tab]Lorem ipsum...`. All of these whitespace characters are collapsed into a single space (much like HTML does).

So the solution is pretty simple: put it all on one line.

```
<s:RichText id="richTxt" width="300">
    <s:textFlow>
        <s:TextFlow>
            <s:p><s:span>Lorem ... diam.<s:br />Morbi ... diam.<s:br />Morbi ... vitae d</s:span></s:p>
        </s:TextFlow>
    </s:textFlow>               
</s:RichText>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly the problem.

Comment: Actually the first/last whitespace should be eliminated instead of being collapsed like it's in HTML. It looks like a poor implementation of the RichText.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove any extra tab or space in your raw text. I'd also try to use a fixed-width font.

EDIT : damn, not fast enough ! ^^